# setting CGIT_CONFIG environment variable in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cgit

I want to set the path of cgit config (CGIT_CONFIG) in a directory with SetEnv.

But it seems that cgit can't find this env variable.
My .htaccess is as follow:

```
Options +ExecCGI +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
#DirectoryIndex cgit.cgi     I named cgit as index.cgi
SetEnv "CGIT_CONFIG" "/home/user_253/etc/cgitrc"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cgi/$1 [END,QSA]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack
RewriteRule .* - [END,F]
```

Of course, I haven't access to main Apache config file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) (part of mod_setenvif) instead to set the environment variable.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf ^ ^ CGIT_CONFIG /home/user_253/etc/cgitrc
```

The `SetEnvIf` directive takes additional arguments, hence the need for two "simple" regex to effectively set the env var unconditionally.

The "problem" with `SetEnv` (mod_env) is that it is processed very late. The request will have already been rewritten to `/index.cgi` (by mod_rewrite) *before* the `SetEnv` directive is processed. Whereas `SetEnvIf` is processed *before* mod_rewrite handles the request. (Directives in Apache config files are not necessarily processed top to bottom. Different modules are processed independently.)

---

*Aside:*

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /index.cgi/$1 [END,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} service=git-receive-pack
RewriteRule .* - [END,F]
```

These two rules are possibly the wrong way round. Any URL that does not map to a file but includes the query string `service=git-receive-pack` will not be blocked.

Comment: Well, according to docs and your perfect answer, it must work... But didn't . I write a shell script as index.cgi and set env variable there and exec the cgit. It works anyway but is something strange...